# Append code into wp-config.php

Tags: php

We have multiple wordpress sites and need to update the wp-config for w3 total cache. We have to append `define('WP_CACHE', true);` into the wp-config.php file. Is it possible to do this via ssh. I don't want to have to go in and open each config file and add it myself.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a question for SuperUser. I'm sure some combination of piping, echo, and the file names from the command line will fix the configs.

Comment: Are all the sites on the same server?

Comment: As stated below, you shouldn't just append this to your wp-config.php file, as it will create unexpected results. Additions to wp-config.php need to come before the line that says `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. Modifying files on a server via SSH is **not a WordPress question**.

Answer (score 1):

This commands prepends a line at the beggining of *yourfile*

```
sed -i 1i"define('WP_CACHE', true);" yourfile
```

To look for many files named wp-config.php and prepend the same text, type this in the shell:

```
for i in $(find . -name wp-config.php) 
do
sed -i 1i"define('<?php WP_CACHE', true); ?>" $i
done
```

Run this from the main folder where you have all the WP sites.

Comment: He would still have to manually specify every file using this method so I am not sure it answer the question from that point of view.

Comment: By this way, you'll end up adding it even before <?php. Can somehow the line number be specified?

Comment: In fact the command sed -i 1i means : insert text before line 1. You could specify any line number.

Answer (score 0):

This will search the server recursively from root (`/`) for all files named `wp-config.php` and append the string `define('WP_CACHE', true);` onto the end of the file.

```
find / -name "wp-config.php" -print | while read i; do echo "define('WP_CACHE', true);" >> "$i"; done
```

Comment: I think you will find your site to behave in an unexpected way if you start putting things at the very bottom of your wp-config.php. Things you add need to come before the line that says `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`.

Comment: Oh I see I know nothing about Wordpresses configuration files and answered with exactly what @SergioPellegrini asked for. This comment should really be made on the question in that case so he is aware.

Comment: I see, you probably answered this before it was migrated to WordPress SE. I will add the comment above.